# Most recently added item is not being animated

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition, linechart

I am trying to use the d3.js library to animate line chart. Eventually, I will be getting data asynchronously from the websocket but for the sake of example, I am just using `setInterval` + `getRandomInt` combination. I need to append new data to the already known data and update the chart accordingly. The important part is that I don't want to erase old data - all the history has to be displayed on the chart indefinitely.

I managed to animate the chart but my problem is that the most recently added item (right end of the chart) is just added without any animation. It just looks weird and I would like to fix that.

I should probably note that I want to display the most recent data as soon as it reaches the browser so hiding the last item is not an option.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Line Graph using SVG and d3.js</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const margins = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
      const width = 1000 - margins[1] - margins[3]; // width
      const height = 400 - margins[0] - margins[2]; // height

      const svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margins[1] + margins[3])
        .attr("height", height + margins[0] + margins[2])
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins[3] + "," + margins[0] + ")");

      const data = [1, 5, 2, 13, 0];

      const x = d3.scale
        .linear()
        .domain([0, data.length])
        .range([0, width]);

      const y = d3.scale
        .linear()
        .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
        .range([height, 0]);

      const lineFunction = d3.svg
        .line()
        .x((_, i) => x(i))
        .y(d => y(d))
        .interpolate("cardinal");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("fill", "none");

      setInterval(() => {
        data.push(getRandomInt(1, 10));

        x.domain([0, data.length]);
        y.domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]);

        svg
          .transition()
          .duration(750)
          .select("path")
          .attr("d", lineFunction(data));
      }, 1000);

      function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this, would be probably duplicate the last node, and then transition it to where it needs to go. However since you rely on index, you would also need an additional parameter for x (else you cannot have two points overlapping).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Line Graph using SVG and d3.js</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const margins = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
      const width = 1000 - margins[1] - margins[3]; // width
      const height = 400 - margins[0] - margins[2]; // height

      const svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margins[1] + margins[3])
        .attr("height", height + margins[0] + margins[2])
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins[3] + "," + margins[0] + ")");

      const data = [{
        y: 10,
        x: 0
      }];

      const x = d3.scale
        .linear()
        .domain([0, data.length])
        .range([0, width]);

      const y = d3.scale
        .linear()
        .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
        .range([height, 0]);

      const lineFunction = d3.svg
        .line()
        .x((d, i) => x(i + d.x))
        .y(d => y(d.y))
        .interpolate("cardinal");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("fill", "none");

      setInterval(() => {        
        data.push({
          y: data[data.length - 1].y,
          x: 0
        });   
        var path = svg
          .select("path");
        path
          .datum(data)
          .attr("d", lineFunction);    
        data[data.length - 1] = {
          y: getRandomInt(1,10),
          x: 1
        };
        x.domain([0, data.length]);
        y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.y; }), 
                  d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
        
        path
          .datum(data)
          .transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attr("d", lineFunction);
      }, 1000);

      function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Well, that's a DYI approach. I'd probably take a look at a plugin like this instead though: https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-interpolate-path .